# AWS Lambda JavaScript SDK async handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

Consider this Node 8.10 code:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => callback(null, "resolved"), 100)
};
```

When I run it the response is `null`. When I remove the `async` keyword from the handler the response is `"resolved"` as expected.

Can anyone explain this behavior? How is the `async` function executed in a Lambda container and what is the difference in a "normal" function?

Comment: Are you sure it returns `null` and not `undefined` ?

Comment: In the test result I see `Response: null`. But even if it was `undefined`, the question is what is the difference in the execution?

Answer (score 3):

The processing of an `async` function differs from a normal one.

Using a normal function, the Lambda container uses the callback function to get the result, even called asynchronously.

But when the handler is defined as `async`, the return value is taken: `var res = await handler(...)` and the callback ignored.